# How can we create slot in IBM Watson assistant using java sdk?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

We are using **ibm-watson java sdk** and trying to build the conversation using the sdk i.e from creating workspace to building a dialog node. But we are unable to create slot in the dialog node. Can anyone guide us that how we can create slots using ibm-watson java jdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't comment on ibm-watson Java SDK, but can share some pieces about the frame/slot model in WA in general.

The hierarchy of dialog nodes in frame/slot model is a bit more complex. In order to create a slot you need to create a particular structure of dialog nodes with special types - e.g. the parent node with type `"type": "frame"`, then the slot node with `"type": "slot"` and with child nodes of type `"type": "event_handler"`. The best way how to get familiar with the model is to create a slot using the `WA` UI, export this as a `JSON` and then inspect the `JSON` structure of dialog nodes to see what goes where.

You might also want to check[Watson Assistant Documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-api.html#modifying-a-dialog-using-the-api) (22.10.2018) that has more insights into particular node types and info how to modify nodes using the `API` calls.